# Does Sparkle require Ruby on the server?

Tags: macos, sparkle

Do you need to have ruby installed on your server to run Sparkle Framework? From what I understand, the framework just looks for the xml RSS feed  on the server and that's it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/sparkle-project/Sparkle/wiki/publishing-an-update):

> Sign your update (unless you’re hosting your update over SSL):
>
> - Sparkle includes a script to help you sign your update.
> - (from the Sparkle distribution root):
> - ruby "Extras/Signing Tools/sign_update.rb" path_to_your_update.zip path_to_your_dsa_priv.pem
> - The string outputted is your update’s DSA signature; you’ll add this as an attribute to your enclosure in the next step.

So, the only reason you would need Ruby is to use the included signing script if you are not distributing your update through a secure connection.

Comment: And you would be doing this on your local machine, not on the server.